# The command button in dialog does not update the outputText with the id given

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, datatable, dialog

I have an outputText in a panelGrid which is also in a fieldset with the id of "foo". And I have a dialog. There is a datatable in this dialog and a commandbutton in the datatable. When I select an item of this datatable, and after clicking the commandbutton, I want the "**foo**" outputText's value to be changed with the data in the datatable in the dialog. But nothing seems to happen. I could use any help. Thanks in advance. Below is my xhtml snippet.
Edit: the method in the backing bean is also added to the post.

```html
<!-- I want the "foo" to be updated with selected data in the dialog's datatable -->
<p:fieldset id="groupConfigurationPanel"
                        legend="#{messages['notificationGroup.title.NotificationGroupConfiguration']}"
                        styleClass="fieldSet">

                <h:panelGrid columns="3"
                             columnClasses="formLayoutLabel, formLayoutInput, formLayoutValidator"
                             rowClasses="formLayoutOddRow, formLayoutEvenRow" cellpadding="0"
                             cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <h:outputText id="offerText" value="Offer" />
                    <h:outputText id="foo"
                                  rendered="#{notificationGroupSupport.instance.offers!=null}" />
                    <p:commandButton value="Select Offer" id="selectOfferButton"
                                     action="#{notificationGroupSupport.retrieveOfferList}"
                                     type="submit" update=":selectOfferForm"
                                     oncomplete="selectOfferVar.show();">
                    </p:commandButton>
                </h:panelGrid>
                
                </p:fieldset>

<!-- This is the dialog -->
<!-- This dialog has a datatable and the commandbutton in this datatable is supposed to update the outputText -->
<p:dialog id="offerDialog" header="Select Offer"
              widgetVar="selectOfferVar" modal="true" resizable="true">

        <h:form id="selectOfferForm">
            <h:panelGrid columns="3" bgcolor="#eff5fa" cellspacing="5"
                         frame="box" styleClass="center">


                <p:dataTable id="offerTable" var="offer" styleClass="dataList"
                             value="#{notificationGroupSupport.offerList}"
                             rowKey="#{offer.offerId}"
                             widgetVar="propertyTableVar" paginator="true" rows="12">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <div align="center">Offer List</div>
                    </f:facet>


                    <p:column selectionMode="single" style="width:18px" />
                    <p:column sortBy="#{offer.offerId}" headerText="ID"
                              filterBy="#{offer.offerId}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                        <h:outputText value="#{offer.offerId}" />
                    </p:column>


                    <p:column sortBy="#{offer.externalOfferId}"
                              headerText="External Offer Id"
                              filterBy="#{offer.externalOfferId}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                        <h:outputText value="#{offer.externalOfferId}" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column sortBy="#{offer.description}"
                              headerText="Description"
                              filterBy="#{offer.description}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                        <h:outputText value="#{offer.description}" />
                    </p:column>


                    <f:facet name="footer">
                        <p:commandButton value="Select" type="submit" id="nonajax"
                                         actionListener="#{notificationGroupSupport.updateOffer()}"
                                         styleClass="ui-priority-primary" ajax="false" update="foo"
                                         oncomplete="propertyTableVar.hide();" />
                    </f:facet>


                </p:dataTable>


            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
```

```
// This is my method for this commandbutton's actionListener in my backing bean. I don't think this is an issue about my backing bean. The method called after select offer button got clicked
 public void updateOffer() 
 {
    campaignList = new ArrayList<Campaign>();
    lifecyclePolicyList = new ArrayList<LifecyclePolicy>();

    List<Offer> offers = getInstance().getOffers();

    for (Offer offer : offers) {

        if ( ( offer != null ) && ( offer.getOfferCampaignPairs() != null                )
                && ( offer.getOfferCampaignPairs().size() > 0 ) ) {
            for ( OfferCampaignPair pair : offer.getOfferCampaignPairs() ) {
                campaignList.add( pair.getCampaign() );
                if ( pair.getPrepaidLifecyclePolicy() != null ) {
                    lifecyclePolicyList.add( pair.getPrepaidLifecyclePolicy() );
                }
                if ( pair.getPostpaidLifecyclePolicy() != null ) {
                    lifecyclePolicyList.add( pair.getPostpaidLifecyclePolicy() );
                }
            }
        } else if ( offer == null ) {
            // todo
            getInstance().setCampaigns( campaignList );
            getInstance().setOffers( offerList );
            getInstance().setLifeCyclePolicies( lifecyclePolicyList );
        }
      }
      initConstants();
    }
```

Comment: Your buttons are wrapped inside a form and the id you want to update also exists and an ajax call happens?

Comment: what do you exactly want to ask? kindly, specify your question.

Comment: Foo is not in the same form than your commandButton, and because of that Foo is not reachable by the update. In this case, change your "update" attribute and include the form name before Foo. Like this: `update=":formFoo:foo"`

Comment: I fixed it. the problem was not what you are offering @Bonifacio. I fixed it with another field in the backing bean, and I added this field into the datatable in the dialog with <selection />. And this way, I have this field updated. So, I could use this field in this purpose. Thanks anyway!